# the (maybe?) opposite of Polysemy?

Tags: word-choice

Well 'opposite' may not be the right word to describe it but here is the question.

Polysemy is the capacity for a symbol to have multiple meanings. On the other hand, a meaning can be described by multiple symbols (George W. Bush, President Bush, etc). Is there a term to describe the second situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for possible meanings and stumbled upon "**multinymy**" and its synonym "**polynymy**" in *"Standardizing and Harmonizing Terminology: Theory and Practice" by Sue Ellen Wright and Richard A Strehlow, editors*.

It's not a common term, and I've not encountered it before, yet it might help.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking, well not entirely correct, but 'synonymy'?

Comment: No, synonymy is ***similarity*** in meaning of different symbols, not the same meaning described by multiple symbols.  Between synonyms there is always some, even if minute, difference.

Answer (score 0):

In almost any credible context where the two concepts might be juxtaposed, it would seem to make sense to use words that are *structurally* "opposite". From [dictionary.reference.com...](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/monosemy)

> **monosemy** *-the fact of having only a single meaning; absence of ambiguity in a word.
>
>   Compare* [**polysemy**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polysemy)

Both those terms are from the perspective of a single word/symbol. If an encoding system contains multiple (monosemic or polysemic) symbols with the same meaning, that's *[semantic] **redundancy***.

Comment: Seems that 'monosemy' is a trait of a single word, not several.  The OP asked about "*a meaning can be described by multiple symbols*".

Comment: @Victor: That's what I meant by "from the perspective of a single word". Though obviously it would be possible to talk about *monosemic / polysemic* languages or other symbol sets (where each symbol has one or multiple meanings). But OP is looking at things from the perspective of the *referent* (is "one thing" represented by only one, or by multiple symbols?). Compare the DNA "symbol set", where [the genetic code is described as **degenerate**, or **redundant**, because a single amino acid may be coded for by more than one codon](http://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/genetic-code-13)